# How to create search experience that covers ASP.NET WebForms app and SharePoint

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sharepoint, search, full-text-search

We have data spread between a SharePoint site(s) and an ASP.NET WebForms application (whose data resides in SQL Server). We are happy with SharePoint's out-of-the-box search experience, but now we want to add similar functionality to our WebForms app. I started to look into SQL Server's full text search capabilities, and started to look into tools like Lucene, and I'm wondering...:

1. Is there a better way to implement a "SharePoint-type" search for our WebForms app than by using SQL Server full-text search? For example, in our WebForms app we keep People data in various SQL Server tables. The user should be able to enter "John Smith" in the search box and ideally all areas of the application that reference "John Smith" would return hits
2. Even better, is there an existing tool or a recommended approach that would allow you to search a SharePoint site *and* a WebForms app (data in SQL Server) at the same time so that users don't have to do two separate searches (one in SharePoint and then again in the WebForms app)?

Comment: I ended up using SQL Server full-text search for the data in the ASP.NET WebForms application, and created a web service as a front-end for that search capability. I also tapped into SharePoint's built-in search web service (we're still using WSS 3.0). Then from my client application where users are initiating their searches, I simply make two separate calls to the two search services and combine the results that are returned before displaying them to the user.